# Выборка по нескольким параметрам SQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Есть сообщения в БД, их, соответственно, нужно достать.
Но есть условие, чтобы комната была равна переменной, или = 'all'.
Объяснил не понятно, поэтому код

> " SELECT * FROM {$table_msgs} room = {$room} OR room = 'all' "

Но такой код работает не правильно, если попадается сообщение с room = all, то выбирается последнее.

P.S. время для меня позднее,голова мало соображает, попытайтесь понять и ответить, пожалуйста.

Comment: @MrGaliev, я так понял из вопроса, что вам нужно объединение двух множеств: записей с `room = {$room}` и записей с `room = all`. Именно это сейчас выполняет запрос, и лично мне не очень понятно, в чем вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
" SELECT * FROM {$table_msgs} where room = '$room' OR 
(room = 'all' and not exists(SELECT 1 FROM {$table_msgs} where room = '$room'))"
```